# Session configured as cookieless causing extra authentication prompt?

Tags: .net, session, authentication

I have a .Net application that is operating in a clustered environment with Windows Integrated Authentication enabled.  To this point it has been running fine except for the fact that Session is used to track the "state" of the application.  Unfortunately users have been opening multiple instances of the application across browser tabs.  As you may know, IE does not treat tabs as a separate instance.  This is causing a problem with the tracking.  In order to work around this I've added the `cookieless="UseUri"` directive to my Web.config and it seems to work fine.  The issue is that at a specific point the application reprompts for authentication credentials.  I believe this is similar to the [double hop authentication](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2008/08/22/iis-windows-authentication-and-the-double-hop-issue.aspx) issue but I've not been able to determine why tracking Session as part of the URI would cause this behavior.  What is happening behind the scenes and how can I override/prevent this behavior?
I suppose if there were a better way to simply separate sessions between browser tabs I'd be up for that, too.

EDIT: 
As a follow-up I've realized that the issue is related to a specific call to a WebMethod from a client-side script (e.g. `mainScreen.ServerMethod("cv0_value", "1");`)

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string ServerMethod(string name, string value)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session[name] = value;
    }
```

I'm not certain how the client and server synchronize session values but it seems relatively intuitive that the issue would be because I'm trying to set a server-side Session value when I'm using the URI for session tracking.  I might be way off but I'm not certain this is possible given the use of the Web.config directive.
I've also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869268/getting-asp-net-cookieless-sessions-and-jquery-ajax-to-play-together-nicely) question on SO related to using Ajax and the cookieless directive which may provide some insight and leads me to believe I may be on the right track.
Am I way off track here?  Is there a solution to having both abilities?

UPDATE:
Beautiful article on [Enabling POST in Cookieless ASP.NET Applications](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/2216431/Enabling-POST-in-Cookieless-ASPNET-Applications.htm).

FURTHER UPDATE:
I have followed the link above and attempted to implement the code but it seems that the values in the check for `ShouldRedirect()` are always returning false so the redirect never takes place.  The description sounds great for the solution but I'm not able to get this working.   Specifically the values for "AspCookielessBoolSession" and "AspSessionIDManagerInitializeRequestCalled" are populated (the HttpContext.Current.Items.Count returns as either 2 or 3) depending on whether the cookieless directive is set to "UseUri" or "true".

At this point I'm open to any solution since I need to maintain Session as unique across windows *and* tabs.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["AspCookielessSession"]` to check if there is session that has already been acquired for the user

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It has been a bit since I've looked at this so I will have to circle around to try your suggestion.  I will get back to you once I have the opportunity.  Thanks.